# ORDER BY clause is not working with UNION ALL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union

My question is as follows:

```
SELECT title, 'dossier' as Source FROM dossier  
UNION ALL 
SELECT title, 'contract' as Source FROM contract ORDER BY `time` LIMIT 5
```

`time` column is present in both tables, but MySQL throws the following error:

> unknown column 'time' in 'order clause'

When I remove `, 'dossier' as Source` and `, 'contract' as Source` the query works correctly.

Comment: please give as the schema of two tables

Answer (score 1):

`order by` clause is applied on the `union all` overall selection here, which doesn't have the `time` column (only `title` and `Source`). What you can do is use a temporary table:

```
select `title`, `source` from (
  select `title`, 'dossier' as `Source`, `time` from dossier  
  union all 
  select `title`, 'contract', `time` from contract
) tbl 
order by `time` 
limit 5
```

Answer (score 1):

@Potashin has one method for solving this.

You should understand that the `order by` is not part of either `select` clause.  It only knows about the columns that are being selected.

Another solution is easy enough . . . that is to simply include `time` in the result set.  What is happening might be clearer if you use parentheses:

```
(SELECT title, 'dossier', time as Source
 FROM dossier  
)
UNION ALL 
(SELECT title, 'contract', time as Source
 FROM contract
)
ORDER BY `time`
LIMIT 5;
```

I should note that if the tables are large and they have indexes on `time`, then the following may be more efficient:

```
(SELECT title, 'dossier', time as Source
 FROM dossier  
 ORDER BY `time`
 LIMIT 5
)
UNION ALL 
(SELECT title, 'contract', time as Source
 FROM contract
 ORDER BY `time`
 LIMIT 5
)
ORDER BY `time`
LIMIT 5;
```